# Number of days since registration

Tags: java

I code a little Console program and now I store the date they joined in a database like.

```
CreateDate
2011-04-15 17:52:57
```

Now I want to do a check like this: a function that gets how many days the guy have been registered.

```
if(player.getDaysSinceRegistration) {
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just for a little more info- is the database entry simply as a string? Does that String include the 'CreateDate' text?

Comment: Can't you just use the Date object? Did you try getting the current date and comparing it against the CreateDate?

Comment: a) To whom refers the 'they' in your first sentence? b) getDays would return an integer, but `if` is testing for a boolean - shouldn't that be `if (p.getDays () > 42)`? What is your problem? Retrieve the date in the database? Calculate the timespan? Compiler errors? The title of your question isn't descriptive too.

Answer (score 4):

[joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) has an easy way to do this:

```
Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(registeredDate), new DateTime()).getDays();
```

Without 3rd party libraries:

```
(System.currentTimeMillis() - registeredDate.getTime()) / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't store dates in databases in textual form.

You should save them as database dates (a type like numbers or varchars), as this will allow you to both ask the database do date calculations as well - the exact way to do so is database specific - as have it automatically pulled up in a Java date object by the JDBC driver which is much easier to work with than strings.  See Bozho's answer for suggestions to do this in the Java layer.