# get formatted date and time in android

Tags: android

I have two function to calculate date and time.

```
  public static String getFormattedDate(String time) {
    long timeUnix = Long.parseLong(time);
    Date myDate = new Date(timeUnix * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yy");
    return simpleDateFormat.format(myDate);
}

  public static String getFormattedTime(String time) {
    long timeUnix = Long.parseLong(time);
    Date myDate = new Date(timeUnix * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    return simpleDateFormat.format(myDate);
}
```

I get the correct output from them which I need.

```
Jul 12 11(date function) and 12:09:45(time function)
```

How can I calculate days from this and how to set am/pm with this.

I  am trying to set time with am/pm if it is today's date and if it is older than show the day(mon,tue,wed etc.) and if it is more than week old than show "MMM d yy".

Comment: 'Calculate days'?  What does that mean?  Surely PM is where hour >= 12?

Comment: hilarious! what's calculate days?

Comment: from calculate days i meant that days of week sun,mon,tuesday.Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For am/pm notation:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss a");
return dateFormat.format(myDate);
```

KK is *hour in am/pm (0-11)*, while HH is *hour in day (0-23)*

Comment: Thanks Fortega.Really helped a lot.

Comment: but i needed to check and accordingly show time if it is of today,or show day if it lies between  past 7 days or show date/month/year if it is more than 7 days old.
how to get this done?

Comment: For this, you could check for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692618/number-of-days-since-registration. If this does not answer your question, you could create a new stackoverflow question for this...

Answer (score 9):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();

DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss z");

String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

System.out.println(localTime);
```

Comment: Single Line: new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())

Answer (score 1):

AM/PM can be retrieved using:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("a");
return dateFormat.format(myDate);
```

There are a few different options for days, best to refer to the [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to decide which day format you need.